# writing t-sql version of .net codes by using sqlclr

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

i have a lot of methods wrote with.net codes (c#) to using with linq queries. but i have problem to translating methods to t-sql. and i want to convert that to t-sql functions and using that with t-sql queries directly. how?

Comment: who is voting to close it? why?

Comment: So you're moving from a nice statically type-safe C# solution, to a messy, hard to manage, TSQL solution?  Yikes.

Comment: @kirk, don't be a hater, there could be many reasons for needing to do this.

Comment: @Kirk i know but my wrote method in c# can't be translated to standard sql using linq! an example of that is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274648/method-boolean-contains-has-no-supported-translation-to-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translating Linq to Sql... I would recommend downloading LinqPad then. Linqpad.net. It should do a reasonable job for you.

Answer (score 2):

Porting data access layers like this is error-prone. I suggest you first create unit tests for all of the methods you want to convert. Then port over to SQL. You don't necessarily want to run the same SQL as is output by LINQ To SQL, as you can likely improve on the performance by hand-coding the queries, but to get an idea of what LINQ to SQL is doing, you can trace the SQL on your SQL Server.

Comment: Even though I posted a response... I have to agree...this is probably a bad idea.