# How do I write a linq to sql query to find records where field name can match one of dynamic number of strings?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have users check off lab facilities in a UI. I want to use linq to fetch corresponding records for all of the labs that they have checked off.

Basically,

```
Dim myRecs = (From l As EpiData In myDataContext.EPIDatas Where l.facility= _ 
              one of the checked labs
```

So basically, I need to write a linq  query where the "strings" to match are determined at runtime. Is there any way to do this easily? I know that there is a library out there called dynamic LINQ, but (1) it's in C# and I'm writing in VB (2) I'm really just looking for a single, simple solution for this single case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please describe where "one of the checked labs" is stored - e.g. is it another enumerable collection?

Comment: Did you really mean "field name" or is this just about the values? Please check the title.

Comment: Are you using Linq to Sql or Linq to Entities?

Answer (score 3):

Use .Contains

```
Dim myRecs = (From l As EpiData In myDataContext.EPIDatas 
              Where listOfCheckedLabs.Contains(l.facility))
```

As a side note, you can safely use a C# library from VB.Net and vice versa.  There may be issues when a library isn't 'CLS compliant'.  This would be the case if the C# library for example had public members that returned `unsigned int` which if memory serves me isn't supported by VB.NET.  This isn't usually the case, since library authors *should* aim for CLS compliant code.

I have tested using Linq to SQL and Linq to Entities, just to satisfy myself that this works - which it does.

Using C# I have code like this that works fine (using LINQPad):

```
var list = new List<string>{ "Test", "Test 2" };
var query = Models.Where (m => list.Contains(m.Description));
```

Comment: .Contains has no translation to SQL. It throws a runtime error. So I need a workaround.

Comment: Can you post a bit more code.  It should be possible to get contains working.

Comment: +1, I wanted to write the same idea. .Contains will be translated to ('element1', 'element2', 'element3'). If it's not getting translated, maybe you have a configuration issue, you should look at the supported functions and if Contains is not supported, you should add Contains too.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments guys. I'm no longer at work, but will re-post the code tomorrow. Here is a post from Jon Skeet on why contains doesn't work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274648/method-boolean-contains-has-no-supported-translation-to-sql